# Is it possible to use a variable for the clientsize?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Form class I have a variable int called BitmapSize.
I want to let the window automatically adjust to the bitmap so I tried setting the clientsize using this variable, BitmapSize.

I get the following warning (no error) when trying to the designer: 
"To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: 
The variable 'BitmapSize' is either undeclared or was never assigned"

Can I just ignore this or is there a cleaner way of achieving what I want? (My code does work as intended..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that at the end of the constructor or in the `OnLoad` handler, not inside the designer-generated function (`InitializeComponent` or whatever), and that will make the designer stop complaining.

Generally mixing anything non-literal into the designer-managed code will confuse it.